# OSGi project with Kotlin dependency

Tags: kotlin, osgi

I'm converting a Java project to Kotlin that gets deployed as an OSGi bundle.  I've included the `kotlin-osgi-bundle` and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.11</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've also included the `kotlin-maven-plugin`, and I can successfully package-up the project.

However, when deployed, I get the following error:

```
Error while starting bundle: file:/D:/Esri/ArcGIS/Server/GeoEvent/deploy/test-0.0.1.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.sample.test [464]: Unable to resolve 464.0: missing requirement [464.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=kotlin)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1245)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1217)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:509)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:358)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:310)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.4.2]
```

I have tried specifying the Kotlin dependency in the `maven-bundle-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <Embed-Dependency>kotlin-osgi-bundle</Embed-Dependency>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This generates a fairly large JAR (4MB) compared to the original Java project (35KB), and when deployed I get the following error:

```
INFO  | curator-framework - 3.1.0 | New config event received: [115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 46, 49, 61, 76, 69, 65, 45, 51, 48, 53, 48, 57, 51, 46, 83, 69, 82, 86, 73, 67, 69, 83, 46, 69, 83, 82, 73, 65, 85, 83, 84, 82, 65, 76, 73, 65, 46, 67, 79, 77, 46, 65, 85, 58, 50, 49, 56, 50, 58, 50, 49, 57, 48, 58, 112, 97, 114, 116, 105, 99, 105, 112, 97, 110, 116, 59, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 58, 50, 49, 56, 49, 10, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 61, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48]
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-framework - 3.1.0 | State change: SUSPENDED
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-framework - 3.1.0 | State change: RECONNECTED
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
INFO  | curator-framework - 3.1.0 | New config event received: [115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 46, 49, 61, 76, 69, 65, 45, 51, 48, 53, 48, 57, 51, 46, 83, 69, 82, 86, 73, 67, 69, 83, 46, 69, 83, 82, 73, 65, 85, 83, 84, 82, 65, 76, 73, 65, 46, 67, 79, 77, 46, 65, 85, 58, 50, 49, 56, 50, 58, 50, 49, 57, 48, 58, 112, 97, 114, 116, 105, 99, 105, 112, 97, 110, 116, 59, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 58, 50, 49, 56, 49, 10, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 61, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48]
INFO  | curator-client - 3.1.0 | Connection string changed to: LAPTOP-3050:2181
ERROR | com.esri.ges.persistence.zookeeper.zk-persistenceutility - 10.5.1 | KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /geoevent/config/clusters/default/deploy/test-0.0.1.jar
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /geoevent/config/clusters/default/deploy/test-0.0.1.jar
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)[23:org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-geoevent:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)[23:org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-geoevent:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:1155)[23:org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-geoevent:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1040)[386:curator-framework:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1023)[386:curator-framework:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callWithRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:67)[387:curator-client:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:99)[387:curator-client:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1020)[386:curator-framework:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:501)[386:curator-framework:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:491)[386:curator-framework:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$4.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:367)[386:curator-framework:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$4.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:309)[386:curator-framework:3.1.0]
    at com.esri.ges.fabric.internal.ZKPersistenceUtility.copyInputStreamToPath(ZKPersistenceUtility.java:338)[77:com.esri.ges.persistence.zookeeper.zk-persistenceutility:10.5.1]
    at Proxy73615e00_3b42_4973_8167_02adcb1d58c6.copyInputStreamToPath(Unknown Source)[:]
    at Proxyca093291_fc2b_46b8_8c21_c244986150ba.copyInputStreamToPath(Unknown Source)[:]
    at com.esri.ges.registry.deploy.internal.DeployFolderRegistryImpl.copyIntoZooKeeper(DeployFolderRegistryImpl.java:73)[169:com.esri.ges.registry.internal-deploy-registry:10.5.1]
    at com.esri.ges.registry.deploy.internal.DeployFolderRegistryImpl.access$500(DeployFolderRegistryImpl.java:37)[169:com.esri.ges.registry.internal-deploy-registry:10.5.1]
    at com.esri.ges.registry.deploy.internal.DeployFolderRegistryImpl$LookForChanges.run(DeployFolderRegistryImpl.java:141)[169:com.esri.ges.registry.internal-deploy-registry:10.5.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_121]
```

This gets repeated a number of times.

Am I missing something, or does this simply mean that the application (Esri ArcGIS GeoEvent) doesn't support OSGi bundles written in Kotlin?

Comment: is `kotlin-osgi-bundle` installed on your osgi runtime?

Comment: @awd it isn't installed on the runtime, that's why I thought if I include the dependency in the bundle it would work.

Comment: you need it on your osgi server, after its installed and active, no need to create a fat jar with kotlin embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bundle simply has a dependency on the `kotlin` package and you need to ensure that this dependency is satisfied.

Breaking this down, it means that your bundle has `Import-Package: kotlin`, which has been derived from the fact that classfiles in the bundle have dependencies on the `kotlin` package. I know very little about Kotlin but clearly the `kotlin` package contains the standard library.

Where you have a bundle that imports a package there must be another bundle that exports that package. This simply means you need to find a bundle that has `Export-Package: kotlin` and ensure that it is deployed into your OSGi Framework alongside your own bundle.

An alternative "solution" is to embed the dependency in your own bundle but as you have discovered, this usually creates far more problems than it solves.